# Few queries about form validation by Angular js

Tags: angularjs, validation

i am new in angular and trying to learn it.

```
https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation
https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation-with-ngmessages
```

i was reading article on form validation by angular js and i stumble in few area which i would like to discuss here.

1) what is difference between `$pristine and $dirty`. both looks same.
2) need to understand `$touched`? what it does ?

3) see the below code

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="name" required>
        </div>

        <!-- USERNAME -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" ng-model="user.username" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="8">
        </div>
```

for first one `ng-model="name"` and second one `ng-model="user.username"`
why some time only property name declared for `ng-model` and why some time we have to write `username dot property name` ?

4) `<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="email">`
`type="email"` is anything specific to `angular or html5?`

5) `<p ng-show="userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine" class="help-block">You name is required.</p>`

they check $invalid and $pristine. can they use $invalid and $dirty instead of $pristine here ?

6) see the code

```
angular
  .module('app', ['ngMessages'])
  .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

function MainCtrl() {

}
```

are they injecting other directive into app module....this is the way to inject

```
.module('app', ['ngMessages'])
```

please see my points and guide me with answer for my each points if possible. your answer would help me to understand and learn angular js.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. $pristine is the inverse of $dirty.
2. The documentation says: *A model is considered to be touched when the user has first focused the control element and then shifted focus away from the control (blur event).*.
3. Because some time you want to bind the control to a variable in the scope, and sometimes you want to bind it to a field of an object that is in the scope. The latter is recommended. In particular, the former causes problems when used inside a directive (like ng-if or ng-repeat) that has its own scope, because it would set the field in the child directive scope instead of the controller scope. As a rule of thumb, always use the latter, and always initialize the object (i.e. user) in the controller.
4. it's both. It's specified in the HTML5 spec, and angular validates that the entered string is indeed a valid email address.
5. yes, since $dirty is the inverse of $pristine
6. That doesn't inject anything. `'ngMessages'` is the name of a **module**. This declaration says that the module 'app' depends on the module 'ngMessages'. So all the directives, services, controllers and filters defined in the ngMessages module will be available in the app module.

Comment: for the point 4 if we remove `type="email"` then what will happen? angular can not validate email?

Comment: @Mou no, angular won't validate the email. How could it know that the value is supposed to be an email if the input is not of type email? And why don't you test it, and read the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

**1)**   **$pristine** is for indicating that the field has not been modified, whereas **$dirty** is for telling it has been modified.

**$pristine**: It will be TRUE, if the user has not interacted with the form yet.

**$dirty**: It will be TRUE, if the user has already interacted with the form.

**2) $touched** tells you whether the user has merely been there/visited.

**$touched**: True if control has lost focus.

**3)** because for **ng-model="name"**, ***name*** property is directly bound to **$scope**, and for **ng-model="user.username"**, ***user*** is bound to **$scope** and ***user*** has a property ***username***. 
Think of it as:- ***user*** is an **object** and ***username*** is its property.

**4)** Not sure, but i think not anything specific.

**5)** **Yes**

**6)** ***Yes*** here you are injecting **ngMessages** in your angular module

Comment: interact with form or not....what does it mean. suppose if i place focus on a text form in a form then what should be consider...interacted ??

Comment: point 3 explanation is not clear. suppose i have model say employee then when we bind some time will write ng-model="name" and some time ng-model="user.salary" this is just not clear. can u plzz come up with relevant sample code to make more clear. thanks